# This code demonstrates the central limit theorem. Is this code "Pythonic"?

Tags: python, data-visualization, matplotlib

I am new to Python, so I am interested in knowing if I am efficiently using python for this project.

This program is meant to simulate the Central Limit Theorem. It uses sliders to adjust the number of measurements and the number of trials.

Central Limit Theorem: Given any distribution, begin sampling by making a series of measurements and averaging them. Imagine that each sample average is the average of 15 measurements. Imagine there are 500 samples. The averages of the samples could be plotted in a histogram. The CLT states that as the number of measurements in each sample is increased, the distribution of the averages of the samples will approach a normal distribution, regardless of the distribution describing what is being measured.

Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Simple_example

I am mostly curious if I am using the function for updating the sliders efficiently.

I am also just looking for general feedback with regards to being "Pythonic".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import random

# Slider Widget added to Central Limit Plot

bins = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)


axTrials = plt.axes([0.25, 0.080, 0.65, 0.05])

axMeasurements = plt.axes([0.25, 0.025, 0.65, 0.05])

sTrials = Slider(axTrials, 'Trials', 1, 500, valinit = 250, valfmt = "%i")
sTrials.label.set_size(20)
sMeasurements = Slider(axMeasurements, 'Measurements', 1, 30, valinit = 15, valfmt = "%i")
sMeasurements.label.set_size(20)


def update(val):

    trial = [0]*int(sTrials.val)

    for i in range(int(sTrials.val)):
        x = 0
        for j in range(int(sMeasurements.val)):
            x = x + random.randint(1, 6)

        trial[i] = x/int(sMeasurements.val)


    ax.cla()
    ax.hist(trial, bins = bins, edgecolor = 'black')
    ax.set_title('Central Limit Theorem with Dice', fontsize = 30)
    ax.set_xlabel('Averages of' + ' ' + str(int(sMeasurements.val)) + ' ' + 'Roles', fontsize = 20, labelpad = 10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency of Means' + ' ' +'(' + str(int(sTrials.val)) + ' ' + 'Trials)', fontsize = 20)
    plt.show()


sTrials.on_changed(update)
sMeasurements.on_changed(update)
```

Comment: Please change the title to state what the program does. Additionally please add a description on what "the Central Limit Theorem" is.

Comment: I made the changes requested.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) will reformat this code to a recognizable and very readable layout.
2. Concatenating strings using `+` is not pythonic. The standard way to do this nowadays is using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).
3. Converting a value *twice* is generally unnecessary. I don't know the `Slider` class, but you could try putting `sTrials.val` etc. straight into an f-string.
4. Python variable names are `python_case` by convention, *not* `camelCase`.
5. `x = x + random.randint(1, 6)` should be written `x += random.randint(1, 6)`.
6. `update` a parameter which is not used in that function. That's a code smell.
7. Abbrs mks cod hrd to rd. `plt` presumably is `plot`. Is `ax` meant to be `axis`? And is `s` `subplot`?

Comment: 7. True, but following conventions makes the code easier to read. I knew what all those variables were just from their names.